# Interpolating bent textrues

Tags: mathematics, interpolation

I am currently making a pressure heat map that will be overlaid on a bent shape (let's say cylinder). I am using a 2d texture that is mapped to the object. The pressure points are also mapped to the texture matrix. As there are only few pressure points giving values, I am interpolating the pressure for the rest of the texture, however, there is an issue...

[image]

As you can see because the texture data is in 2d array the interpolation does not account for the place where it connects.

Is there an algorithm that would help account the borders of the matrix being connected?

Comment: It's not immediately clear from the image what kind of formula you're using at present — there are quite a few approaches that could create a similar visual. Can you share more details or even a minimal code sample to explain your current method, and describe what the desired outcome should be instead?